# WSO2 EI: Registry issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Frequently, WSO2 EI server getting crashed in our local environment with registry issue and every time this issue occurred I used to change the server bundle to sort this out is there any permanent solution to fix this issue?

If possible can someone explain why this issue occurred it would help me to understand why it's occurring.

[image: Log Error]

Comment: Are you using any Connectors?

Comment: Yes I'm using gmail,file,salesforcerest connectors.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be observed if the `<registryPath>` is not configured in [Salesforce init configs](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-salesforcebulk/blob/release-1.0.7/docs/config.md#initializing-the-connector). The connector might add a corrupted entry to the registry when invoking the service due to this missing config. In the latest versions of the Salesforce Connectors, this value has been [set by default](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-salesforcebulk/blob/release-1.1.0/src/main/resources/salesforceBulk-config/init.xml#L38), hence you do not need to provide them separately.